# Filter button not clickable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, protractor

I am trying to click a filter button in order to sort a list alphabetically. I press a filter which is the .first() of the filters and it works fine, it is the same code just with a different name. Now I want to click on the third, nothing. I have tried to do wait functions and isVisible however am yielding no results and element is still not visible.

```js
browser.driver.sleep(3000);
//clicks the area filter button
element.all(by.css("[data-bind='text: displayName, visible: displayName']")).get(3).click().click();
browser.driver.sleep(3000);
```

```html
<th data-bind="click: $root.orderBy, nonScrollableTooltip: { text: tooltip, shift: [-10, 40] }">
  <span data-bind="text: displayName, visible: displayName">Area</span>
  <span class="capacity-icon" data-bind="class: icon, visible: icon" style="display: none;"></span>
  <span class="order-indicator order-asc" data-bind="css: { 'order-asc': sortOrder().name == 'asc', 'order-desc': sortOrder().name == 'desc' }"></span>
</th>
```

I really am just confused on what to do here.

Comment: Just to confirm: you see all 6 if you through the same steps manually?

Comment: @Nick they are filter links and they are all visible on the screen.  One is names (the first one), next is area (second), ceiling height (third), etc. etc.

Comment: @Nick I can click name and it will order the list.  I cannot click any other filter link, getting an error not visible. Doesn't make sense as they are all identical in code.

Comment: if you know exact element's you can try using this locator: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText

Comment: is there any way you can make the filters unique? maybe chaining elements? maybe you're not really clicking on what you think you're clicking. if you use chrome, Inside the dev tools I use the magnifying glass icon a lot to identify elements. this gif explains what I mean http://i.imgur.com/thyaMzY.gif?1

Comment: @Barret I'm using firefox element picker and that is what i'm using.  I have tried multiple ways including xpath, makes no sense to me why not visible.

Comment: @Sergey I need to return a list that is underneath it.  Really all I'm doing is clicking that link and it flips the list around.

Answer (score 0):

when you say you want to click on the third. I am guessing the third object in the array?

I see you're currently using

```
element.all(by.css("[data-bind='text: displayName, visible: displayName']")).get(3).click().click();
```

however this would click on the 4th object in the array b/c the [.get()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) function takes an index where 0 is the first object in the aray.

So if you want to click the third object in the array then you would actually use this

```
element.all(by.css("[data-bind='text: displayName, visible: displayName']")).get(2).click().click();
```

.get(0) gives you the first object **also the same as .first()**

.get(1) gives you the second object

.get(2) gives you the third object

**UPDATE:**
I'm not sure why it's not visible? but sometimes using this expected condition has helped me with element not visible issues.

```
  var filter = element.all(by.css("[data-bind='text: displayName, visible: displayName']")).get(3);
  var IsClickable = EC.elementToBeClickable(filter);
  browser.wait(IsClickable, 5000, "failed to click on the filter").then(function() {
     filter.click().click();
  });
```

Comment: I need to click on all of them essentially with that css tag there is like 6 however only the first is coming up as visible.  Its happening across all.  the (2) is empty.

Comment: Questions?
1. when you say empty, did you get an error message when trying to click the (2)

2. from my understanding, the filters aren't visible ? are these filters in a dropdown menu? I assumed they were all visible above columns  from the code sort order showing asc and desc

Comment: No I just skip over it and goto 3. at some point another filter will be added there.